# Error while trying to send mail from swing GUI in Jython

Tags: java, python, swing, jython

I've made a basic GUI with a send button that calls the function sendmail which works fine when called outside the GUI. But when the button is clicked, I get the following error :

> janv. 13, 2016 11:15:35 AM org.python.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe register
>   AVERTISSEMENT: Force-closing a channel whose registration task was not accepted by an event loop: [id: 0xa8bc713e]
>   java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: event executor terminated

I've tried making the function a method of my class Window, but I get the same error.

Here's the sendmail function (works fine outside the GUI) :

```
def sendmail(test):
    try:
        sender = "myemail@gmail.com"
        recipient = "toemail@hotmail.com"

        # Message container
        msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
        msg['Subject'] = "Link"
        msg['From'] = sender
        msg['To'] = recipient

        # Body of the message
        html = """\
        <html>
          <body>
            <p>big<p>
          </body>
        </html>
        """

        part = MIMEText(html, 'html')
        msg.attach(part)

        mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        mail.ehlo()
        mail.starttls()

        mail.login('myemail', 'mypassword')
        mail.sendmail(sender, recipient, msg.as_string())
        mail.quit()

        print "Email was sent succesfully."
    except:
        print "Unexpected error: could not send email."
        return 0
    return 1
```

Here's the Window class :

```
class Window:
    def sendclicked(self, event):
        sendmail()

    def __init__(self):
        window = JFrame("Email application", defaultCloseOperation=JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE, size=(255, 400), locationRelativeTo=None)

        panel = JPanel()

        tolabel = JLabel("To :", SwingConstants.RIGHT)
        tolabel.setPreferredSize(Dimension(50, 20))
        tofield = JTextField(15)

        subjectlabel = JLabel("Subject :", SwingConstants.RIGHT)
        subjectlabel.setPreferredSize(Dimension(50, 20))
        subjectfield = JTextField(15)

        messagetextarea = JTextArea("")
        messagetextarea.setPreferredSize(Dimension(222, 200))

        sendbutton = JButton("Send", actionPerformed=self.sendclicked)
        sendbutton.setPreferredSize(Dimension(109, 20))

        savebutton = JButton("Save as draft")
        savebutton.setPreferredSize(Dimension(109, 20))

        infofield = JTextField(20)
        infofield.setEditable(False);

        panel.add(tolabel)
        panel.add(tofield)
        panel.add(subjectlabel)
        panel.add(subjectfield)
        panel.add(messagetextarea)
        panel.add(sendbutton)
        panel.add(savebutton)
        panel.add(infofield)

        window.add(panel)
        window.setResizable(True)
        window.visible = True
```

And finally my main :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Window()
```

What is causing the problem here and how can I fix-it?
Thank you.

**Edit #1 :** The problem starts on this line, but I can't seem to figure out a way to fix it.

```
mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
```

Here is the complete error log : http://pastebin.com/d01TT8Ge

The second error block might help someone figure out what's wrong with my cod:

> janv. 13, 2016 12:21:54 PM org.python.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise execute
>   GRAVE: Failed to submit a listener notification task. Event loop shut down?
>   java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: event executor terminated

**Edit #2 :** additionnal information about my system

- Using NetBeans IDE 8.1
- Jython 2.7.0
- OS : Windows 7
- JDK 1.8 (Default)

I sadly don't have access to another system where I could try running my program. If you need more information, please let me know in the comments!

Comment: SOA#1: Works for me. Add more information about your system: Jython version, JDK version, OS. Can you try it on other system?

Comment: @MichałNiklas I just added the information you asked about, thank you for your time. Do you mind telling me on what system where you when my program worked? Also, what does "SOA#1" mean? Thank you.

Comment: What happens when you change your implementation of `Window.sendclicked()` to just `print('sendclicked')` and run it from console (`cmd.exe`)? On my Linux machine it simply prints `sendclicked` on console, what happens on your machine?